# How can I split file into several parts using javascript, and insert these details into a Mysql db on an external server?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

I have a file which contains some sort of database, it's written like this :

`name = blah blah`
`num = xxx xxxxxxxx`
`addrs = xx , blah blah`
`name = blah blah`
`num = " xxx xxxxxxxx`
`addrs = xx , blah blah`
..... ans do on.......

The file's extension doesn't matter (actually I created it)

Its a local file, so i want to insert these values into my website's DB ...
and it should be inserted like this :

blah blah        xx,blah blah      xxx xxxxxxxx
blah blah        xx,blah blah      xxx xxxxxxxx

what should I use , is it Javascript/php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to have the file uploaded, and then let your server handle the importing using PHP.